# Angular 6 delay the loop

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, ngfor

I have a question about angular loops. I would like to delay the rendering process on a ng-for. For example,

```
<div *ngFor="let data of items | delay">
  <app-my-component [data]="data"></app-my-component>
</div>
```

Delay 10ms for each render. The "items" array comes from another component that I can't change it. Also, the "items" array size can be increased and decreased. Maybe, I can redirect it with observable struct. I have tried observable with async but I can't achieve. Can someone show me an example ?

Comment: Why you want to delay it? i didnt get the point.

Comment: There exist performance issue. Too much element is rendering at same time.  So if I can render each element with an interval the performance will increase.

Comment: @alim: IMO, Rendering wouldn't be a problem but what happens after so many items are rendered. What happens on every button click, keyInput, etc. Change detection would run for all those rendered items. You may need to think over the ChangeDetection strategy, or decreasing the change detections, or the rendered items themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is interesting question and couldn't found exact question on the SO.

**This is my solution**, I wrote helper methods for easier understanding and future code reuse:

**My solution** on [Live StackBlitz editor Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-delay-the-loop)

```
import { from, timer, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {
  scan,
  map,
  concatMap,
  share,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

const timeOf = (interval: number) => <T>(val: T) =>
  timer(interval).pipe(map(x => val));

const timed = (interval: number) => <T>(source: Observable<T>) =>
  source.pipe(
    concatMap(timeOf(1000)),
    map(x => [x]),
    scan((acc, val) => [...acc, ...val]),
  )
```

---

**And the usage is:**

```
  arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  arr$ = from(this.arr)
    .pipe(
      timed(1000),
    )
```

---

**As for HTML will be:**

```
<div *ngFor="let i of arr$ | async">
    <b>{{ i }}</b>
</div>
```

---

**As for explanation:**

`from(this.arr)` will emit each of the array items separately and then I am using `concatMap()` for each emitted item to the `timer(1000)`, which is essentialy delaying each emitted item for 1 second. Finally, I am using `scan()` operator to combine each emitted item back in the final accumulated array.

Comment: I think this is what I need, I will take look this after the weekend but one question what happens the items collection updateded outside observable ? I mean what if I add a few items to items collection, do I need to reconstruct the observable object ?

Comment: It will not trigger redraw, in this exact case. What is your desired functionality when main items gets updated? Tell me and I will give you updated solution

Comment: I have a item collection that first items will removed  beginning of the collection and a new items will be added to end of the collection. And, this can be applied more than once. You can think it like virtual scroll

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of async pipe to load an observable

```
//define your delay observable
this.delayItems=of(items).pipe(delay(1000))
```

in your template

```
<div *ngFor="let data of delayItems | async">
  <app-my-component [data]="data"></app-my-component>
</div>
```

> Update

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { from, timer, Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  arr$:Observable<any[]>
  constructor() {
    this.arr$=from(this.arr).pipe(
    concatMap(item=>timer(1000).pipe(mapTo(item))),
    scan((acc,curr:number)=>acc.concat(curr),[])
  )

  }
}
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let i of arr$ | async">
    <b>{{ i }}</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably, you will need `from(items)` instead of `of(items)`. "from()" will change each element to an Observable

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: I got this '''ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.''' am I missing something ?

Comment: `delay(1000)` will simply delay emitting of items for 1 second, then it will emit whole array and this won't be what OP wants. This will just delay drawing of whole array for 1 second.

Comment: if you want to have delay in between each item then @Goga Koreli will work